# Document is not defined on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, visual-studio-code

I tried to google about this problem but I couldn't solve it...Im using visual studio code.

I think something essential part is the problem but I can't find out need help..
seem as If I just use built in objects or functions in javascript i does works. but when Im using external stuffs failure happens.

```
{/usr/local/bin/node test.js 

  log: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  warn: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  dir: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  time: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  timeEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  timeLog: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  trace: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  assert: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  clear: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  count: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  countReset: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  group: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  table: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  debug: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  info: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  dirxml: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  error: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupCollapsed: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  Console: [Function: Console],
  profile: [Function: profile],
  profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
  timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
  context: [Function: context],
  [Symbol(kBindStreamsEager)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kBindStreamsLazy)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kBindProperties)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kWriteToConsole)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kGetInspectOptions)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kFormatForStdout)]: [Function: bound ],
  [Symbol(kFormatForStderr)]: [Function: bound ]
}
/Users/jisang/Desktop/haha/test.js:5
console.log(document);
            ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jisang/Desktop/haha/test.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

my code is this

```
console.log(console);

console.log(document);
```

Comment: If you're running the code in Node, then there is no `document` - the code doesn't run in a browser or other document context.